# how can I access part of website that isn't visible through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


moin_url = 'https://www.themoin.com/currency/info'
moin = requests.get(moin_url)
print(moin.status_code)


moin_root = '#root > div > div.sc-kRktcz.gouydu > section > section > div.sc-hQXzsD.jFmkJH'


moin_soup = BeautifulSoup(moin.content, "html.parser")
moin_rate = moin_soup.select_one(moin_root)
moin_exchange_rate = moin_rate
print(moin_exchange_rate)
```

this is my code right now, and I want to extract an exchange rate. However, it keeps returning `None` I'm puzzled because the same code works for another exchange rate site. I found articles on dynamic content but I can't find the Json file for it so I couldn't start in the first place.

[all I want to do is extract this number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Zqy.png)